# Running sqlite3 query in node.js returns `undefined` rows with no error

Tags: node.js, sqlite

Using `Node.js 4.2.1` with `sqlite3 3.1.1` The following code -

```
var sqlitedb = new sqlite3.Database(sqliteFilename);
sqlitedb.serialize(function() {

   sqlitedb.run("SELECT ZDATA FROM ZMYTABLE;", function(err, rows) {
      console.log(rows);
   });

});
sqlitedb.close();
```

Prints `undefined` in the console, but if the same query is executed using the `sqlite3` tool, it works fine -

```
$ sqlite3 backup.sqlite 
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> SELECT ZDATA FROM ZMYTABLE;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
...
```

Any idea why SQL returns `undefined` rows in Node.js?

Comment: Have you checked if the code returns an error?

Comment: Have you tried removing the semicolon from the query string?  I wouldn't expect it to cause an error, but it shouldn't need to be there.

Comment: Can you include some of your table data and structure so it's testable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method [`run()`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaserunsql-param--callback) does not return a value and in the callback, only returns an error if one occurred.

To fetch data, you should use [`get()`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databasegetsql-param--callback) or [`all()`](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#databaseallsql-param--callback).

This will work perfectly:

```
sqlitedb.serialize(function() {
   sqlitedb.get("SELECT ZDATA FROM ZMYTABLE;", function(err, rows) {
        console.log(err);
        console.log(rows);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 3.1.1 is not supporting Node.js 5.0.0. We should wait update of sqlite3.

Comment: It also happens in `Node.js 4.2.1`.

Comment: `The sqlite3 module works with Node.js v0.10.x, v0.12.x, v0.4.x, and v0.5.x.`